# How to make text more distant from images using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How do I separate the descriptive text to make it more distant from the image I tried to fix it but it didn't work and how can I fix it so that my text is postponed to make it more distant from the image Thank you
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>show details</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/style.css">
        <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            .book-details{
                background-color:#f5f5f5;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="d-flex justify-content-between my-4">
                <h4>show details</h4>
                <hr>
            </header>
            <div class="book-details p-5 my-5">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">
                            <img src="../Problem_image/<?= $rowDd['image'];?>" width="600">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">
                            <h5>name:</h5>
                            <p><?= $rowDd["name_surname"];?></p>
                            <h5>phone:</h5>
                            <p><?= $rowDd["phone_number"];?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are currently setting the image width to 600px which makes it overflows the `col-md-6` bootstrap container.

In order to fix that you need to set it to `100%` so it aligns with your layout.

**Try this:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>show details</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/style.css">
      <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
        .book-details{
            background-color:#f5f5f5;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="container">
        <header class="d-flex justify-content-between my-4">
        <h4>show details</h4>
        <hr>
            </header>
            <div class="book-details p-5 my-5">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">
                  <img src="../Problem_image/<?= $rowDd['image'];?>" width="100%">
                 </div>
            
                 <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">
                 <h5>name:</h5>
                 <p><?= $rowDd["name_surname"];?></p>
                 <h5>phone:</h5>
                 <p><?= $rowDd["phone_number"];?></p>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The problem is caused by the image overflowing the container.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this result, you can insert an empty column. Also, your image should have `width` set to `100%` so that it aligns with your layout.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">
        <img src="../Problem_image/<?= $rowDd['image'];?>" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 order-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5 order-md-3">
        <h5>name:</h5>
        <p><?= $rowDd["name_surname"];?></p>
        <h5>phone:</h5>
        <p><?= $rowDd["phone_number"];?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The problem is caused by the image overflowing the container.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the issue is due to the image overflowing its container.  This is easily fixed by using the Bootstrap class `img-fluid` instead of inline styles.

```
<img src="../Problem_image/<?= $rowDd['image'];?>" width="600">

<img src="../Problem_image/<?= $rowDd['image'];?>" class="img-fluid">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">
            <img src="//placeholder.pics/svg/600" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">
            <h5>name:</h5>
            <p>Jenny</p>
            <h5>phone:</h5>
            <p>867-5309</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The problem is caused by the image overflowing the container thank you